# Как добавить свою кнопку в Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress

```html
<div>
    <a -label="Link more" href="#" gv-link="link_3" class="btn btn-decor js-check-text sticky-link">
       <span><i class="icon-star"></i>отправить<i class="icon-star"></i></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

При добавлении классов кнопки в шорткод, подхватывает их, но не корректно. Скорее всего из-за псевдоклассов after и befor, могу ошибаться. Какие ещё могут быть варианты, ну кроме создания своей формы, чтобы кнопка работала в созданной форме Contact Form 7?

Comment: Костыль: добавить вышеуказанный код в саму форму, submit input скрыть и добавить js-код на клик по ссылке для тригера клика на скрытый submit. Также можно обойтись только JS или полной заменой вывода input submit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896192/how-to-replace-input-type-submit-to-button-on-contact-form-7

Comment: Кнопка для чего?

Comment: для ОТПРАВКИ формы

Comment: Зачем несколько кнопок для ОТПРАВКИ формы?

Comment: у меня не получилось применить мои классы к дефолтной кнопке. Есть варианты? Го.